# how to custom excel report from query in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have the code, it convert query from GridView to excel.
and the data placed in the cell "A1" to end of datas,
the question are how could i custom excel report like to add a Header title report name and insert an image in that excel report
and how i set the where cell the report placed.

this bellow ma code

```
Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Using sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        'To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = False
        Me.bindingData()

        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
        For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor
        Next
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
            For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
                Else
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor
                End If
                cell.CssClass = "textmode"
            Next
        Next

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
        'style to format numbers to string
        Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { } </style>"
        Response.Write(style)
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.[End]()
```

Comment: This just exports HTML masquerading as an Excel file. You've got a string containing some HTML, so you could add whatever you like to that before sending. Or find a library (there are free ones) which create actual Excel files and will probably give you more structure and more control.

Comment: I second that notion. Spreadsheetlite is a good open source library you can use. Gives you a lot of control over the design of the spreadsheet.